# Drag and drop JavaScript query

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //mouse down on dragged DIV element
    var flag = 0;
  
    function startdrag(t, e) {
    if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault(); //line for IE compatibility  
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        t.style.position = "absolute";
        window.document.onmousemove = dodrag;
        document.getElementById("resulttable").onmouseup = end;
        window.document.onmouseup = stopdrag;
        window.document.s = t;
        return false;
    }
    //move the DIV  
    function dodrag(e) {
        //alert("dodrag");
        if (!e) e = event; //line for IE compatibility
        
        t = window.document.s;
        if (t != null) {
            t.style.left = (t.offsetLeft + e.clientX - t.dragX) + "px";
            posleft = (t.offsetLeft + e.clientX - t.dragX) + "px";
            t.style.top = (t.offsetTop + e.clientY - t.dragY) + "px";
            t.dragX = e.clientX;
            t.dragY = e.clientY;
        }
        return false;
    }
    //restore event-handlers
    function stopdrag(e) {
        if (flag == 1)
            window.document.s = null;
        else
            alert("outside valid range"); // code for setting object to original area
        return false;
    }
    function end(e) {
        flag = 1;
        return false;      
    }
</script>

//  table  from where we start dragging
<td id="<%= i %>"><div onmousedown="startdrag(this, event);"> <%Response.Write(row1[i].ToString());  %></div> </td>


// target div where to put element
<div id="resulttable" onmouseup="end(event);" >Put whatever you want in here<br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
    </div>
```

PROBLEM:

1. When I start dragging, all statements of `startdrag()` are called and then `dodrag()` and so on.
2. `end()` is not called even though we put element on target div, so `flag` remains as 0.

Comment: have you considered using jquery ui? They have build in functionality for drag drop, move and a lot more... it handles browser incompaibility internally...

Comment: `window.document.s` What's that?

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, if you can use Jquery UI and Jquery as it will do all the heavy lifting.

With regards to your question try end() stopdrag(), javascript can work very differently across browsers, check in another browser to see if the call actually works... console.debug("method called"); is a good command to add to your code to help with debugging...